# Add element to arrays, that are values to a given key name (json transformation with jq)

Tags: jq

I'm a jq newbie, and I try to transform a json (a Swagger spec). I want to add an element to the array value of the "parameter" keys:

```
{
  ...
  "paths": {
    "/great/endpoint1": {
      "get": {
        "parameters": [] <<--- add a value here
       }
    }
    "/great/endpoint2": {
      "post": {
        "parameters": [] <<-- and here too here too etc.
  ....
```

The following jqplay almost works. It adds values to the right arrays, but it has the nasty side effect of also removing the "x-id" value from the root of the input json. It's probably because of a faulty if-condition. As the paths contain a varying string (the endpoint names), I don't know how to write a wildcard path expression to address those, which is why I have tried using `walk` instead:
https://jqplay.org/s/az56quLZa3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sample data is incomplete, it's difficult to say exactly what you're looking for but it looks like you should be using `parameters` in the call to walk:

```
walk(if type=="object" and has("parameters")
     then .parameters += [{"extra": "value"}]
     else . end)
```

If you want to restrict the walk to the top-level `paths`, you would preface the above with: `.paths |=`

Comment: Thanks! This works! Gosh, before posting here I spent hours trying to get the syntax for this right. When I couldn't, I tried the above variant with existence of key "schema" in the first element. Now it looks right and works right! Thanks!